# How to sort pandas data frame using values from several columns?

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'c1':3,'c2':10},{'c1':2, 'c2':30},{'c1':1,'c2':20},{'c1':2,'c2':15},{'c1':2,'c2':100}])
```

Or, in human readable form:

```
   c1   c2
0   3   10
1   2   30
2   1   20
3   2   15
4   2  100
```

The following sorting-command works as expected:

```
df.sort(['c1','c2'], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
   c1   c2
0   3   10
4   2  100
1   2   30
3   2   15
2   1   20
```

But the following command:

```
df.sort(['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])
```

results in

```
   c1   c2
2   1   20
3   2   15
1   2   30
4   2  100
0   3   10
```

and this is not what I expect. I expect to have the values in the first column ordered from largest to smallest, and if there are identical values in the first column, order by the ascending values from the second column.

Does anybody know why it does not work as expected?

**ADDED**

This is copy-paste:

```
>>> df.sort(['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])
   c1   c2
2   1   20
3   2   15
1   2   30
4   2  100
0   3   10
```

Comment: What version of pandas and numpy are you using?

Answer (score 79):

`DataFrame.sort` is deprecated; use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

```
>>> df.sort_values(['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])
   c1   c2
0   3   10
3   2   15
1   2   30
4   2  100
2   1   20
>>> df.sort(['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ampawake/anaconda/envs/pseudo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Suggestion: reverse order with original on bottom, update up top. Reading top down I tried the first block and wondered why it failed, being doubly confused by "it works for me" and "did you paste as is" (surely it was my fault!). Then I scrolled and saw the update...

Answer (score 28):

Use of `sort` can result in warning message. See [github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3014) discussion.
So you might wanna use `sort_values`, docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Then your code can look like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])
```

Comment: I am getting warning otherwise `/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/start_ipython_kernel.py:1: FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)`

Comment: @patapouf_ai No, `sort` is now deprecated

Answer (score 9):

The dataframe.sort() method is - so my understanding - deprecated in pandas > 0.18. In order to solve your problem you should use dataframe.sort_values() instead:

```
f.sort_values(by=["c1","c2"], ascending=[False, True])
```

The output looks like this:

```
    c1  c2
    3   10
    2   15
    2   30
    2   100
    1   20
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the accepted answer didn't work:

<strike>f.sort_values(by=["c1","c2"], ascending=[False, True])</strike>

Only the following worked as expected:

```
f = f.sort_values(by=["c1","c2"], ascending=[False, True])
```

Comment: Seriously? There is something called [inplace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) in Pandas you know

Comment: Seriously, Inplace didn't work for me, otherwise I wouldn't have created a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing this code as a script file then you will have to write it like this:

```python
df = df.sort(['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to be really useful:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : range(0,10) * 2, 'B' : np.random.randint(20,30,20)})

# A ascending, B descending
df.sort(**skw(columns=['A','-B']))

# A descending, B ascending
df.sort(**skw(columns=['-A','+B']))
```

Note that unlike the standard `columns=,ascending=` arguments, here column names and their sort order are in the same place. As a result your code gets a lot easier to read and maintain.

Note the actual call to `.sort` is unchanged, `skw` (*s*ort*kw*args) is just a small helper function that parses the columns and returns the usual `columns=` and `ascending=` parameters for you. Pass it any other sort kwargs as you usually would. Copy/paste the following code into e.g. your local `utils.py` then forget about it and just use it as above.

```
# utils.py (or anywhere else convenient to import)
def skw(columns=None, **kwargs):
    """ get sort kwargs by parsing sort order given in column name """
    # set default order as ascending (+)
    sort_cols = ['+' + col if col[0] != '-' else col for col in columns]
    # get sort kwargs
    columns, ascending = zip(*[(col.replace('+', '').replace('-', ''), 
                                False if col[0] == '-' else True) 
                               for col in sort_cols])
    kwargs.update(dict(columns=list(columns), ascending=ascending))
    return kwargs
```

Comment: This seems like overkill, compared to other options.

Comment: only look at the example, not the `sortkwargs` function. that is a one off definition that you can store away and import from your e.g. `util.py`. your code will be so much more flexible and readable compared to the default `sort` syntax.

Comment: vote down all you like, please add a comment so I can improve the answer

Answer (score 1):

Note : Everything up here is correct,just replace **sort** --> **sort_values**()
So, it becomes:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
 df.sort_values(ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

Refer to the official website [**here**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).