# Sort Pandas DataFrame by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I Know this question has a lot of answers, for example: [How to sort pandas data frame using values from several columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618981/how-to-sort-pandas-data-frame-using-values-from-several-columns)

I tried the solutions given by the users, but I cannot get a sorted column.

I built a DataFrame:

```
weekly = {'Tweet ID': Series(tweetID),
          'Fecha de Publicación': Series(tweetDate),
          'Tweet': Series(textStatus),
          'Retweets': Series(retweetCount),
          'Favoritos': Series(favoriteCount),
          'Hashtags': Series(hashtags),
          'Menciones': Series(mentions)}

weeklyAnalysis = DataFrame(weekly)
```

Then I call for specific tweets:

```
maxTweets = weeklyAnalysis[['Tweet', 'Retweets']]
                          [weeklyAnalysis['Retweets'] >= promedioRts]
```

This is what I tried, in order to sort retweets column:

```
maxTweets.sort_values(by=['Tweet', 'Retweets'], ascending=[False, True])
```

How can I actually sort that *retweets* column.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to sort that df by 'retweets'? use:

```
maxTweets_sorted = maxTweets.sort_values(by='Retweets')
```

Comment: Exactly! It works perfectly. Thanks. I think this solution applies for every specific DataFrame built as `maxTweets`.

Answer (score 7):

By default pandas does not sort in place, unlike Python's `list`.

Change

```
maxTweets.sort_values(by=['Tweet', 'Retweets'], ascending=[False, True])
```

to

```
maxTweets = maxTweets.sort_values(by=['Tweet', 'Retweets'], ascending=[False, True])
```

or pass `inplace=True`

```
maxTweets.sort_values(by=['Tweet', 'Retweets'], ascending=[False, True], inplace=True)
```