# sort column based on specific column | python | pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
c234  0.876   0.456   0.876
c561  0.9527  0.263   0.9527
c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
c561  0.8231  0.975   0.975
```

I want to sort `4th column` within each `1st column`, the output will be like this:

```
c234  0.876   0.456   0.876
c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
c561  0.8231  0.975   0.975
c561  0.9527  0.263   0.9527
c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) with `ascending` as a boolean list to determine direction:

```
df.sort_values([0,3], ascending=[True, False])
```

Output:

```
      0       1       2       3
1  c234  0.8760  0.4560  0.8760
0  c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
4  c561  0.8231  0.9750  0.9750
2  c561  0.9527  0.2630  0.9527
3  c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
```

Comment: Also add following link :  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: This is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287938/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-value

Comment: Note that this will sort by the first column, then by the fourth.  If you want to sort by the fourth, but keep the original order for the first column, it's more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

### `sort_values` takes a list of columns

Assuming your column names were `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

```
df.sort_values([0, 3], ascending=[True, False])

      0       1       2       3
1  c234  0.8760  0.4560  0.8760
0  c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
4  c561  0.8231  0.9750  0.9750
2  c561  0.9527  0.2630  0.9527
3  c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
```

---

### Preserve row placement

Assume the first column is not sorted **and** you don't want it sorted.  You just want the rows within each group sorted.

```
df.loc[
    df.groupby(0)[3].transform(
        lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).index
    ).astype(df.index.dtype)
]

      0       1       2       3
1  c234  0.8760  0.4560  0.8760
0  c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
4  c561  0.8231  0.9750  0.9750
2  c561  0.9527  0.2630  0.9527
3  c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
```

---

But that isn't interesting.  Suppose the dataframe were this instead

```
      0       1       2       3
0  c561  0.9527  0.2630  0.9527
1  c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
2  c234  0.8760  0.4560  0.8760
3  c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
4  c561  0.8231  0.9750  0.9750
```

Notice that `'c561'` is at the top and more at the bottom.  We can sort them and keep there same row positions.  Let's run the last solution again.

```
      0       1       2       3
4  c561  0.8231  0.9750  0.9750
2  c234  0.8760  0.4560  0.8760
1  c234  0.4255  0.2348  0.4255
0  c561  0.9527  0.2630  0.9527
3  c561  0.4111  0.1543  0.4111
```